# How to find if an integer occurs in another integer

Tags: python

Is there a way to find if an integer occurs in another integer? For example if two integers A and B are given. Integer A occurs in Integer B at position P then the leftmost position should be returned.

For example, 53 occurs in 1953786 at position 2, so the function should return 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert both to strings:

```
b = 1953786
a = 53
str(b).index(str(a))
# 2
```

Note this finds the first occurrence only, if there are multiple.

Two possible bumps in the road as pointed out by @user2357112:

1. The search isn't linear time. The runtime characteristics are quite complicated - it's better than linear if some of the speed tricks the implementation uses work out, and quadratic in the bad cases. [quoting directly there]
2. In the quadratic-time scenario, `str()` constructor itself will run into trouble for very large ints.

Comment: The search isn't linear time. The runtime characteristics are quite complicated - it's better than linear if some of the speed tricks the implementation uses work out, and quadratic in the bad cases. (However, if you're hitting the bad cases, your inputs are also big enough that Python's quadratic-time base conversion will be a problem in the `str` implementation.)

Comment: If you can read C, take a look at [stringlib/fastsearch.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h)

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the original question.  If you want to know all the occurrences rather than just first, you can do:

```
import re
a=1553545355343
b=53

all_ocurrences = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(str(b), str(a))]
print(all_ocurrences)

#[2, 6, 9]
```

If you care for just the first left most position, you can go for Brad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Brad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919768/244297), [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) will raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found. If this is not desirable, you can use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which returns `-1` on failure:

```
>>> a, b = map(str, [53, 1953786])
>>> b.index(a)
2
>>> b.find(a)
2
>>> b.index("52")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
>>> b.find("52")
-1
```

The notes about the runtime characteristics also apply here.